# Cannot install Wine, no matter what I try

Tags: wine

This question has been asked many times, and I went through the solutions posed in many of them. I keep getting the same error

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have purged wine multiple times, but I still get this error.

Edit 1:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Edit 2:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.1~trusty)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It's not about wine. It's about your package conflicts. Please show us the complete output of an apt upgrade.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Put output in your question, properly formatted. Not as a comment.

Comment: Now show us complete apt output where you try to install something. Anything.

Comment: Reposted the apt upgrade output in question along with the output from install attempt.

Comment: Ah, now it's clear: You have unwisely added a source that provides software *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. Uninstall ALL packages provided by that source. Then delete the source. Don't use it again. Is there some reason you cannot use the quite nice version of Wine already in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: How do I figure out the source? And my attempts to install the version of wine in the Ubuntu repositories also fail.

Comment: You figure out the source using your notes and /etc/apt/sources*. Or ppa-purge (search for it). Of course Wine won't install while you still have the offending packages. You must clean up this mess completely before starting the next.